# Saving Locust response in CSV

Tags: python, csv, response, locust

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <m:NumberToWordsResponse xmlns:m="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
      <m:NumberToWordsResult>four hundred </m:NumberToWordsResult>
    </m:NumberToWordsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

To store the response from locust in a csv file, I tried it but it saving it in char and comma format for example: "x,m,l"

I tried it with string also but not working in expected way. Is there is any solution for it..? any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code and input/output .

Comment: yes I have added the input please check it out

Comment: Please also show what your expected output format will be. Also it is better to copy/paste as text rather than an image, that way we can also copy paste it to test with